# Expected number of coin flip

Tags: probability, expected-value

I need to calculate the expected number of coin flips needed to get two consecutive heads.

Below is my approach -

- Expected number 1. Probability is 0 (because I need atleast 2 tosses)
- Expected number 2. It is HH. Probability is .5^2
- Expected number 3. It is THH. Probability is .5^3

So on.

So my total expected number will be infinite sum of 2*.5^2 + 3*.5^3 +...

Is my approach correct? If not, where am I doing wrong?

Is there any finite value of above sum?

Your pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your approach *can* be correct... but it hardly seems like you will be able to finish with that approach.  What appears in the $+\dots$ will just get more and more difficult.  You should consider using markov chains instead.  "*Is there any finite value of above sum?*"  Yes, of course.

Comment: The sum is *not* $\sum_{k=2}^\infty k\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{k} = \frac{3}{2}$.  To stop at 4 flips, TTHH, but also HTHH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) problem. Suppose we stop flipping once we get two consecutive heads We have the following states:

- The last flip was tails.
- The last flip was heads

Let $a, b$ denote the expected value of the number of steps it takes to stop flipping from each state. Here
$$a = 1 + \frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b$$
$$b = 1 + \frac{1}{2}a$$
and solving gives $a=6$ and $b=4$.
From the starting state, this is equivalent to if the last flip was tails, so the expected value is $\boxed{6}$.

Comment: could you please explain how you come up the 1st equation?

Comment: If the previous flip was tails, then we flip a coin. That's where the +1 comes from. If we land heads, then we move to the second state. If we land tails, we stay in the first state.